# Charge MacBook with USB (Adapters?)

Tags: usb, power, charger

I want to buy an [external charger](https://stacksocial.com/sales/power-vault-18-000mah-dual-usb-battery-pack), it has USB. Are there any adapters (including transformators, I think that might be needed, right?) so I can charge my MacBook with the external charger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not possible.

The USB can not carry the Voltage (14 V) and Current (> 1 Amp) required to charge MBP.

If it is for the car, you can try this product [http://www.amazon.com/Spal-Magsafe-Adapter-Charger-Notebook/dp/B009G1B22O](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009G1B22O)

Answer (score 0):

There're external batteries like this: [http://www.amazon.com/HyperJuice-External-Battery-MacBook-Smartphones/dp/B009I5AZTY](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009I5AZTY)

Comment: Well those are extremely expensive. And I wanted to know whether there are adapters.